# Is there objective evidence that the US economy is "booming"?

Tags: gdp, economic-growth, united-states

I realize that it's the political pundits that are saying it, but they never seem to provide evidence that the  economy is "booming".  The dictionary definition of "booming" is **having a period of great prosperity or rapid economic growth**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly standard measure to use would be Gross Domestic Product (GDP). Over the past 30 years, US GDP has been growing at approximately 2.5%.

According to trading economics

> The US economy expanded an annualized 2.3 percent on quarter in the first quarter of 2018, below 2.9 percent in the previous period but beating market expectations of 2 percent

Using this measure, calling it a boom is a bit much.

Another way to cut the data is by comparing it to the ten-year trend of about 1.5%. Growing 80bps above trend looks a bit better.

So, to answer your question, depending on how you cut the data, it could be considered booming but I wouldn't.